# How can I make the background image to be responsive without losing the proportions

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am doing an animation with **HTML** and **CSS3** and I need adapt along with the background image. The problem is that the content stay within that `div`. I put the `height` and width `fixed` for this but don’t work. When I try using dynamic proportions (`%` or `auto`) and `background-size: contain;` the animation does not follow the original path.

With fixed size following the path:

[image]
and mobile works fine too

[image]

but, not is responsive:

[image]

With dynamic size is responsive, but not follow path:

[image]
[image]

Changed code:

```
 #main{
   position:relative;
-  left: 0;
-  height: 1366px;
-  width: 980px;
+  // left: 0;
+  height: 100%;
+  width: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   background: url('../images/bg.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
-
+  background-size: contain;
 }
```

[*DEMO*](http://codepen.io/luizcarvalho/pen/VjVOKK)

This is my *index.html*

```
  <div id="main">
    <div class="participant" style="z-index: 4;">
  <div class="car">
      <img class="photo" src="https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c21.21.259.259/s50x50/529297_568082979888645_1727470385_n.jpg?oh=c75505b8b23ff9abd26be1fd5771f81d&amp;oe=582BAD0F" alt="">
      <img class="sprite" src="http://i.imgur.com/OwYhg9T.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>


  </div>
```

And my `animation.css`

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}


body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#main{
  position:relative;
  left: 0;
  height: 1366px;
  width: 980px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/G4gs6EG.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}



@-moz-keyframes move
{
  from {
    right: -30%;
    top: 8%;
  }

  to {
    right: 140%;
    top: 80%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move
{
  from {
    right: -30%;
    top: 8%;
  }

  to {
    right: 140%;
    top: 80%;
  }
}

.participant {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  right: 140%;
  top: 80%;
  -moz-animation:move 10s  linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move 10s  linear  infinite;
}

.sprite{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.photo{
  position: relative;
  top: 128px;
  left: 99px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little tricky and requires fixed aspect ratio of the background image.

### 1. Make everything responsive.

First of all, it won't work if everything is `%-based` but the car is `px-based` (because if you resize your window everything will get smaller but the car will stay the same), so for starters you are going to have to change the size of your car to percentages.

### 2. Fix aspect ratio.

Then you need to fix the aspect ratio using [mix of absolute and relative positions and paddings](http://www.goldenapplewebdesign.com/responsive-aspect-ratios-with-pure-css/).

In your case your wrapper's CSS will look something like:

```
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 71.74%; /* 980/1366 = ~ 0.7174 */
```

(your background image is 980x1366px)

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ytba997c/)

### 3. FUTURE PROOF: Fill the screen on every screen.

Unfortunately you can't do much about white space around your image because of the aspect ratio itself, I'd personally look for a 16:9 image for the background and it will fit most of the desktop/laptop screens perfectly, if you need to cover wide range of screens then you should use media queries with different-sized backgrounds.

Remember to adjust the `padding-bottom` of your container along with the image itself.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing height and width in your #main css class to:

```
#main{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/G4gs6EG.png") no-repeat fixed center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I've got this working on codepen.io

http://codepen.io/NosNits/pen/RRqzPy

Comment: don't work... same problem without `height: auto;` and with it don't show nothing.

Comment: I made a modification to the css I posted before and I have this working on codepen.io.  Take a look.

Comment: I made one more modification.  Image is fully responsive like you asked.  Try to modify the path of your car.

Comment: But I need with car, follow the path in any sizes.